# SQL Server Floating Point in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point

I'm trying to query a database, I need to get a list of customers where their weight is equal to  60.5. The problem is that 60.5 is a real I've never query a database with a real in a where clause before.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight=60.5
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight=cast(60.5 as real)
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight=cast(60.5 as decimal)
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight=convert(real,'60.5')
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight=convert(decimal,'60.5')
```

These queries return 0 values but in the Customers table their are 10 rows with Weight=60.5

Comment: What is the exact type of the column `Weight`?

Comment: The exact type of the column Weight is real.

Comment: What do you get if you run `SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight BETWEEN 60 and 61`? There are very few reasons to use real or float. Real is definitely not a candidate for a persons weight unless this is an application for the space shuttle. use decimal(19,2) instead

Comment: Why? I don't know that wasn't my assertion. The space shuttle part was really just a snide comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is that floating point numbers are inaccurate by definition. Comparing what seems to be 60.5 to a literal 60.5 might not work as you've noticed.

A typical solution is to measure the difference between 2 values, and if it's smaller then some predefined epsilon, consider them equal:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE ABS(Weight-60.5) < 0.001
```

For better performance, you should actually use:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Weight BETWEEN 64.999 AND 65.001
```

Comment: This could be made sargable by using a range predicate instead.

Comment: @MartinSmith - agreed!

Answer (score 2):

If you need equality comparison, you should change the type of the column to `DECIMAL`. Decimal numbers are stored and compared exactly, while real and float numbers are approximations.

@Amit's answer will work, but it will perform quite poorly in comparison to my approach. `ABS(Weight-60.5) < 0.001` is unable to use index seeks. But if you convert the column to `DECIMAL`, then `Weight=60.5` will perform well and use index seeks.

Comment: I think that's a useful general advice, but not necessarily applicable here (or in other places).

Comment: I'm on the +1 camp, but I must exclaim and say I don't like the "competitive style".

Comment: I've downvoted this because this is no solution to the question posed (how to do WHERE on Real column); instead it suggests a non-trivial change in the table...

Comment: Hey @Amit, I actually upvoted your answer and I agree that it answers the question. I added my answer as a generally better approach (in my opinion, at least), of which the OP hasn't thought. It might fit his needs better. I did not mean to compete with you, but still I needed a way to point out the differences between the two approaches. If you can suggest a better way of wording, I would appreciate it. Thanks!